# Dynamic Table in Blazor horzontal data braked on group id

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I need a dynamic table in balzor basically it will have a serious of columns A-B B-C and within those columns will lie a series of numbers for example

This is the data from the locker table

| ID | ItemID | IsRented | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | False | 1 |
| 2 | 10002 | True | 1 |
| 3 | 10003 | False | 1 |
| 4 | 10004 | True | 1 |
| 5 | 20005 | False | 2 |
| 6 | 20006 | True | 2 |
| 7 | 20097 | False | 2 |

Locker Defination

```
public  class Locker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int? LockerId { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public string? RowId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? Size { get; set; }
    public bool? IsRented { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int? BookingId { get; set; }
    public int? Book { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsModified { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Where it would print a table with

This is table I want produced?.

| ID | A - B | B - C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 20001 |
| 2 | 10002 | 20002 |

A - Z Along the top then the groups along the rows but the group id is how I no it should change to a differnt column ie 1000s should be in column a 2000s should be in column b.

What I have tried so far in blazor is

Html Markup

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in headings)
        {
        <th>item</th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach(var item in Elements)
        {
            @if(item.IsRented==true)
            {
                <td style="color:red"> &nbsp;</td>
            }else
            {
                <td style="color:green"> @item.LockerId</td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

The above table gets it data from the web service below but as you see above would print out all the elments for each A ,B ,C D but I dont want that is there a way to use the group id effencitally here.

```
@code {
public List<Locker> Elements { get; set; }
private bool _readOnly;
string[] headings = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ,"G","H"};

private Func<Locker, string> _cellStyleFunc => x =>
  {
      string style = "";

      if (x.IsRented == false)
          style += "background-color:#00FF00";
      else
          style += "background-color:#FF0000";
      return style;

  };

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
         Elements = new List<Locker>();
        string url = Constants.BaseUrl + Constants.GetAllLockers;
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            Elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locker>>(content);
        }
    }
}
```

My Linq to get all the items.

```
public IEnumerable<Locker> GetAll()
{
  return _context.Lockers.Where(w=> w.IsActive==true && 
                          w.IsDeleted == false).AsEnumerable();

}
```

Comment: I fail to see a relationship between the two tables, and the code is pretty gobbledegook.  Mostly API stuff that gets some form of data we have no access to.  What we need is a definition of `Locker` and a dummy data set to work with.

Comment: Their not two tables the data is clearly shown in the table and its not gobletgook do u have to be so dam rudd the defination if locker is shown in the first table !

Comment: [Polite] Succinct rather than rude: gobbledegook (my meaning) = not obvious to anyone other than the writer: a common problem in questions. The question, as it is, doesn't provide enough information for anyone to answer it: you haven't seen anyone else even comment. All the code around getting the information from the API isn't really needed, just some dummy data and a definition of Locker.  In short a "Minimum Reproducible Example". Unless I'm not seeing it (quite poss) where is Locker defined. Happy to help, but to do so I (and probably anyone else looking at this) needs more information

Comment: Edit to add the locker definiation @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: Do you want to convert row values to columns? I could not figure out what you mean.